# How can I specify expiry time on session in django>=1.6?

Tags: django, python-2.7

It works only if I set `SESSION_SERIALIZER = "django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer"` in the settings file.

Here is my code:

```
...
    tz = timezone.utc
    expire_time = timezone.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(oa_token_expire_time).replace(tzinfo=tz)
    request.session.set_expiry(expire_time)
...
```